# Get the vector Norm without absolute values?

Tags: vector-calculus

I want to get the Norm of a vector which involves sines and cosines (So I really need to replace it by the Pythagorean theorem). Since I know that all my results are going to be real and positive I don't care about the Abs before squaring the terms.

How can I get 
$$ \sqrt{ r_x ^ 2 + r_y ^ 2 + r_z ^ 2 }$$

Instead of:
$$ \sqrt{ |r_x| ^ 2 + |r_y| ^ 2 + |r_z| ^ 2  }$$

Comment: `Sqrt[vec.vec]` where `vec` is your vector. `.` in *Mathematica* is the dot product.

Comment: @C.E. Thanks! I was doing it with loops but I didnt expect such elegant solution! Could you add it as an answer please?

Comment: `Norm[vec] // ComplexExpand`

Comment: As @BobHanlon says (and I thank you) ComplexExpand is more generalized solution to annoying complex numbers problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That expression is the square root of the dot product of the vector by itself:

```
Sqrt[vec.vec]
```

where `vec` is your vector.