# Derivative of a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-calculus

I [learned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143740/get-the-vector-norm-without-absolute-values) not use the Norm[] function when computing vector derivative, so I use the dot product instead:

```
In: D[x.x, x]
Out: 1.x + x.1
```

What does the result mean? Is 1=(1, 1, .., 1) here? Why can't it show just `2x` as the result?
And Mathematica won't resolve it when I define `x`?

```
In: 1.x + x .1 /. x -> {3, 4}
Out: {0.3 + 1.{3, 4}, 0.4 + 1.{3, 4}}
```

Comment: One way to approach this to define x = Array[a, 3]; Then you can take the derivative x = 
D[x . x, {x}] and you'll get more what you expect. Otherwise it doesn't know what the dimensions of x are (if its a scalar, vector, matrix).

Comment: Thanks, now it makes sense why, since it might be a matrix. Can I tell it the "type"? I tried `$Assumptions = (x) \[Element] Vectors[2, Reals];` but it didn't help. Also, if I use `Array[a, 3]`, can I resolve `a` at some point? For example, take a derivative and then compute it for certain vector. `D[x.x, {x}] /. x -> {1, 2, 3}` doesn't seem to work

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89651

Comment: There is not really a nice way to generically say "x is a 3 vector" using assumptions. But if you think about it, x = Array[a, 3]; is effectively a declaration that x is an arbitrary 3 vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @bill s, you can write

```
x = Array[a, 3];
deriv = D[x . x, {x}]
(* {2 a[1], 2 a[2], 2 a[3]} *)
```

Note that the you need to put `{x}` rather than `x` (otherwise it will attempt to interpret the 2nd item in the list as the order of the derivative - see the help for `D` - the syntax is rather over loaded).

The easiest way to substitute values is perhaps

```
deriv /. Thread[x -> {1, 2, 3}]
(* {2, 4, 6} *)
```